# Is there a netwire equivalent of stepper?

Tags: haskell, frp, netwire

Reactive-banana has a function named `stepper` (of type `MonadMoment m => a -> Event a -> m (Behavior a)`), which converts an event into a behaviour where the behaviour's value is the value of the last event, or the initial value if no event has occurred yet.

In a talk by Conal Elliott, the name of which I cannot remember, he presents this as being one of the fundamental operations on events and behaviours. However, I cannot find a similar function in netwire. With my limited understanding of netwire, I would expect it to have type:

`a -> Wire s e m (Event a) a`

- Does netwire have an equivalent function?
- If not, is there any reason why this is not possible?
- Is anything similar possible, i.e. ways of converting events into behaviours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function I was looking for is called [`hold`, in `Control.Wire.Interval`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.2/docs/Control-Wire-Interval.html#v:hold).

This does not need an initial value, because the wire inhibits until the first event is received. If this behaviour is needed, it can be implemented like so

```
stepper init = hold <|> pure init
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess why netwire doesn't provide that. Everything in `Control.Wire.Event` keeps the results in `Event`s preserving the knowledge of when they are happening.

You can get out of `Event`s by using one of the methods of switching in [`Control.Wire.Switch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.2/docs/Control-Wire-Switch.html). You're looking for [`rSwitch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.2/docs/Control-Wire-Switch.html#v:rSwitch).

```
-- Beware: untested, untype-checked code
stepper :: (Monad m) => a -> Wire s e m (Event a) a
stepper init = switcher . source
  where
     -- source :: Wire s e m (Event a) ((), Event (Wire s e m () a))
     source = arr (\e -> ((), pure <$> e))
     -- switcher :: Wire s e m ((), Event (Wire s e m () a)) a
     switcher = rSwitch (pure init)
```

In the code above `pure` is used as `a -> Wire s e m () a` to create trivial wires.